# If-else error statement `the condition has length > 1`in R?

Tags: r, if-statement

I am writing a simple ifelse statement following another , where I'm trying to classify the index into three groups ( >= 0.8, 0.8 to -0.8, <= -0.8)

I keep getting an error:

> In if (df$index >= 0.8) { :   the condition has length > 1 and only
>   the first element will be used

```
index <- c(0.8,0.2,-0.2,0,-1,-1)
df <- data.frame(index)
df$indexclass <- NA


df$indexclass  <- if (df$index >= 0.8) {
  df$indexclass  <- "P"
} else if (df$index <= (-0.8)) {
  df$indexclass  <- "A"
} else { df$indexclass <- "S"}
```

Comment: since your `length(df$index)` is greater than 1 it is giving you warning. Use `ifelse` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `ifelse` instead of `if/else` because `if/else` expects a vector of length 1 and is not vectorized for length greater than 1.

```
df$indexclass  <- with(df, ifelse(index >= 0.8, "P",
        ifelse(index <= (-0.8),  "A", "S")))
df$indexclass
#[1] "P" "S" "S" "S" "A" "A"
```

---

If there are multiple comparisons, an option would be either `cut` or`findInterval`

```
c("A", "S","P")[with(df,  findInterval(index, c(-0.8, 0.8)))  + 1]
#[1] "P" "S" "S" "S" "A" "A"
```